# How to print unicode symbol to console

Tags: c, console, codepages

I want to print ▌ symbol to console.
I tried

```
printf(L"▌");
```

and

```
wchar_t t = L'\u2588';
wprintf(L"%c\n", t);
```

But i get only '?' in result.
I use Visual Studio 2012

**Update**

if I set the locale to *en-US*

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-US");
```

I get `|` for `█`, `+` for `╫` and `_` for `▄`

Comment: That last update shows your console is well aware of what you are attempting, and chooses a close approximation to the characters it cannot display. What OS is this? (Guessing Windows.) Is it possible to set your console to use UTF-8? "Code pages" are [so pre 2003](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable unicode in console we should use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
void main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"█");
}
```

- http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=98
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tw4k6df8.aspx